# Is it possible to perform SQL Query with distributed join over a local cache and a partitioned cache?

Tags: ignite

I am currently using apache ignite 2.3.0 and the java api. I have a data grid with two nodes and two different caches. One is local and the other partitioned.

Lets say my local cache is on node #1.

I want to perform an SQL query (SqlFieldsQuery) with distributed join so that it returns data from local cache on node #1 and data from partitioned cache on node #2.

Is it possible? Do I need to specify the join in some particular order or activate a specific flag?

All my current tests are not returning any rows from partitioned cache that are not located on same node as local cache.

I tested the same query with distributed join over two different partitioned cache with no affinity and it was able to return data from different nodes properly. Is there a reason why this wouldn't work with local cache too?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `setDistributedJoins(true)` on `SqlFieldsQuery`?

Comment: Yes. IIn my examples, the distributed join flag works between two partitioned caches but not between a local and a partitioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to perform joins (both distributed an co-located) between LOCAL and PARTITIONED caches. The workaround is to use two PARTITIONED caches.

Comment: You can also run distributed joins between PARTITIONED and REPLICATED caches